# Serialize string keys separated by dots with value to Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using a Database to save Json Structure and Values. Using Testdata the Structure as Dictionary would look similar to this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> input = new Dictionary<string, string>();
input.Add("application.shortName", "TestShortName");
input.Add("application.longName", "TestLongName");
input.Add("application.description", "TestDescription");
input.Add("application.deepNode.evenDeeperNode", "Values so deep, you can see Adelle rolling");
input.Add("common.yes", "YesTest");
input.Add("common.no", "NoTest");
input.Add("common.save", "SaveTest");
input.Add("common.pager.pagesLenghtBefore", "LengthTestDeepNode");
```

I never know the names that come from the Database so it could be any name for the key and any depth indicated by a dot something like: "key1.key2.keyN".
Now I want to serialize every key and value I get from the database into Json. With the Testdata from above it would look like this:

```
{
  "application": {
    "shortName": "TestShortName",
    "longName": "TestLongName",
    "description": "TestDescription",
    "deepNode": {
      "evenDeeperNode": "Values so deep, you can see Adelle rolling"
    },
    "common": {
      "yes": "YesTest",
      "no": "NoTest",
      "save": "SaveTest",
      "pager": {
        "pagesLengthBefore": "LengthTestDeepNode"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using JSON.NET but I barely scratched the surface and don't know if there is a Method for this. I know I can convert Dictionaries to Json but because of the unknown depth of my keys, that isn't directly possible. I tried to come up with a loop that splits the keys and adds values to the last splitted node, though I was never able to actually program something like that.

I hope this doesn't seem like an inappropriate question but I really need help with this. I appreciate any tips in the right direction. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using Dictionary<string, object> instead? That way, you could nest input["application"] = new Dictionary<string, object>() and so, respresent the JSON structure more accurately in your object graph.

Comment: This sounds like the way I want to go. I read something like this but couldn't come up with a solution yet. I will work more in this direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of Dictionary you can use dynamic object, like:

```
var input = new {application = new {shortName = "TestShortName",
                                    longName = "TestLongName"
                                     ....},
                 common = new {yes = "YesTest",
                                  ..........}
                 }
```

Or using [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
dynamic input = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
input.application = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
input.application.shortName = "TestShortName"
input.application.longName = "TestLongName"
.
.
.
input.application.deepNode.evenDeeperNode = "Values so deep, you can see Adelle rolling"
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the names that come from the database. I get a string like "key1.key2". Will I still be able to use dynamic objects then? I will edit the Question to point that out further

Comment: Good answer. I believe you can use ExpandoObject as Dictionary too.

Comment: Okay looking into this a little more I found out that you can add Properties by String names to ExpandoObject. This is a really nice approach and I will use it for my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @ame-no-kenshi I know this is an old question, but how did you resolve this in the end please? 
Could you give an example of the code you used based off the example you gave please? 
I have exactly the same issue. Thanks

Comment: @Dom
Sorry I haven't been active in a while... I should still have that code and will update the question with the code I used to resolve it.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to convert dictionary to json, then following snippet will do it for you:

```
        var input = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        input.Add("application.shortName", "TestShortName");
        input.Add("application.longName", "TestLongName");
        input.Add("application.description", "TestDescription");
        input.Add("application.deepNode.evenDeeperNode", "Values so deep, you can see Adelle rolling");
        input.Add("common.yes", "YesTest");
        input.Add("common.no", "NoTest");
        input.Add("common.save", "SaveTest");
        input.Add("common.pager.pagesLenghtBefore", "LengthTestDeepNode");

        var res = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
        foreach(var pair in input)
        {
            var key = pair.Key;
            var parts = key.Split('.');
            var currentObj = res;
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length-1; i++)
            {
                var property = parts[i];
                if (!currentObj.Keys.Contains(property))
                    currentObj[property] = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
                currentObj = (new Dictionary<string, Object>())currentObj[property];
            }

            currentObj[parts[parts.Length - 1]] = pair.Value;
        }

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res, Formatting.Indented);
```